# problem to find this kanji

Tags: kanji

Can you help me with this kanji , I can't find it ...
[image]

Comment: Is this it, 用. Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 用. It can mean quite a few things depending on the context, but it's probably "use".

Comment: What he said! :D

Comment: serry miss... /:)